# Minimize $E(m)=\sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} {m \choose i} \cdot [c \cdot (\frac{N}{m})^2]^i \cdot[1-c \cdot (\frac{N}{m})^2]^{m-i}$

Tags: inequality, optimization, binomial-coefficients

Minimize over $m$ the expression:

$E(m) = \sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1} {m \choose i} \cdot \left[ c \cdot \left(\frac{N}{m} \right)^2 \right]^i \cdot \left[1 -  c \cdot \left(\frac{N}{m} \right)^2 \right]^{m - i}$

where $c > 0$ is a constant such that $1 -  c \cdot \left(\frac{N}{m} \right)^2 > 0$ and $n \leq m \leq N$.

The problem is to minimize $E(m)$ over integer $m$ such that $n \leq m \leq N$.

Because of the binomial coefficients, using the derivative does not seem to be an option and I am not sure what types of inequalities to use that could simplify the problem.

If you have any suggestion about how to tackle this problem I would much appreciate.